# How can I search Git branches for a file or directory?

Tags: git, branch

In Git, how could I search for a file or directory by path across a number of branches?

I've written something in a branch, but I don't remember which one.  Now I need to find it.

**Clarification**:  I'm looking for a file which I created on one of my branches.  I'd like to find it by path, and not by its contents, as I don't remember what the contents are.

Comment: I'm unclear about the question. Was this file in a branch that is now deleted? Was the file deleted?

Answer (score 598, accepted):

`git log` + `git branch` will find it for you:

```
% git log --all -- somefile

commit 55d2069a092e07c56a6b4d321509ba7620664c63
Author: Dustin Sallings <dustin@spy.net>
Date:   Tue Dec 16 14:16:22 2008 -0800

    added somefile


% git branch -a --contains 55d2069
  otherbranch
```

Supports globbing, too:

```
% git log --all -- '**/my_file.png'
```

The single quotes are necessary (at least if using the Bash shell) so the shell passes the glob pattern to git unchanged, instead of expanding it (just like with Unix `find`).

Comment: This works if you know the exact path to `somefile`: if you need regex search over the path/filename, for example, then you can use ididak's answer.

Comment: Supports globbing, too: `git log --all -- **/my_file.png`

Comment: I used this for a slightly different problem. I was trying to find all the *.sql files I had committed to a particular branch. So I used `git log --grep='branch' --author='me' -- *.sql`. Worked like a charm. git version 1.7.11.1

Comment: Note that `gitk` supports the globbing as well. That is an excellent answer @webmat! If you want to see where it's been deleted / created /etc, you can use `git log --all --stat -- **/my_file.png`, that way you won't have to guess if you're checking it out from a commit that deleted it.

Comment: @webmat: I took the liberty of adding your information about globbing to the answer. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: which need to use two asterisk? only one would not be enought?

Comment: @AlexN. You use two asterisks to cover multiple levels of subdirectories.

Comment: For those wondering (and make it this far down the comments!): `--all` => "Pretend as if all the refs in refs/ are listed on the command line as <commit>".

Comment: Note that you should write a file name like mentioned above (with asterisks): **/file.txt. Else it will show nothing.

Comment: This answer ought to mention that the (full) relative path is needed for the first Git command (`git log --all -- somefile`).

Comment: if you only know the name, better run this command from the root of repository. As @PeterMortensen said you need to specify `the (full) relative path`, so `**/filename` won't work if you have to descend folders to find the file. probably there's a syntax for that?

Comment: Jeez, you just saved my sanity. That moment, when you implemented something weeks ago, the branch is still open, and you simply can't find the regarding files in the mess of the other 100 branches.

Comment: For Windows CMD use double quotes for globbing 
git log --all -- "**/file.name"

Answer (score 80):

git ls-tree might help. To search across all existing branches:

```
for branch in `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads`; do
  echo $branch :; git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | grep '<foo>'
done
```

The advantage of this is that you can also search with regular expressions for the file name.

Comment: A few hopefully helpful comments: (a) You probably want to add "-r" to "git ls-tree" so that it'll find the file even if it's in a subdirectory.  (b) A perhaps neater alternative to the first line would be to use "git for-each ref", e.g. "for branch in `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads`; do" (c) "git ls-tree --name-only" will make the output tidier (d) it might be worth pointing out in your answer that there's an advantage of this over Dustin's solution, namely that you don't need to exactly know the filename - you can search by regular expression matching any part of the path

Comment: I wrapped this up in a script so you can run "gitfind.sh <regex>"; the gist is https://gist.github.com/62d981890eccb48a99dc

Comment: Note that this will only search across *local* branches. To search remote-tracking branches, use `refs/remotes` instead of `refs/heads`. To search everything (local branches, remote-tracking branches and tags), just use `refs/`.

Answer (score 27):

Although [ididak's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/372654/848072) is pretty cool, and *Handyman5* provides a script to use it, I found it a little restricted to use that approach.

Sometimes you need to search for something that can appear/disappear over time, so why not search against all commits? Besides that, sometimes you need a verbose response, and other times only commit matches. Here are two versions of those options. Put these scripts on your path:

**git-find-file**

```
for branch in $(git rev-list --all)
do
  if (git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | grep --quiet "$1")
  then
     echo $branch
  fi
done
```

**git-find-file-verbose**

```
for branch in $(git rev-list --all)
do
  git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | grep "$1" | sed 's/^/'$branch': /'
done
```

Now you can do

```
$ git find-file <regex>
sha1
sha2

$ git find-file-verbose <regex>
sha1: path/to/<regex>/searched
sha1: path/to/another/<regex>/in/same/sha
sha2: path/to/other/<regex>/in/other/sha
```

See that using [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) you can modify that script to alternate searching all commits, refs, refs/heads, been verbose, etc.

```
$ git find-file <regex>
$ git find-file --verbose <regex>
$ git find-file --verbose --decorated --color <regex>
```

Checkout https://github.com/albfan/git-find-file for a possible implementation.

Comment: Did you mean "Now you can do git-find-file <regex>"? I got it working, thank you!

Comment: I personally find it much more useful to use $(git branch | cut -c 3-) instead of $(git rev-list --all). I don't care about finding a bunch of commits, I care about named branches.

Comment: I also changed the scripts to use $(git branch | cut -c 3-) since the loop over all commits was much too slow.

Comment: Seen all the fuss I thing is worth to create a repo for this. https://github.com/albfan/git-find-file. I have open some issues, feel free to propose more or send PR for it.

Comment: @ElijahLynn if you want to use `git find-file` you can do by adding it as git alias, just run `git config --global alias.find-file '!git-find-file'.

Comment: @lumbric installing script on path works out of the box, its a git feature

Comment: To use branches only $(git branch | cut -c 3-) only lists local branches and needs to cut. Can use `$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes refs/heads)` instead to list local and remote branches directly. In addition the sed line here contains '/' which will not work with '/' in the branch name, they can be changed to '~' which is an illegal char in a branch name to avoid that problem.

Comment: @Zitrax Thanks for comments. Now you can install script, have man page, color, refnames, all in a single command

Comment: Presuming what platform? Linux?

Answer (score 16):

#### Command Line

You could use `gitk --all` and search for commits "touching paths" and the pathname you are interested in.

### UI

[image: ui fields]

(Credit to: @MikeW's suggestion.)

Comment: As stated, use gitk --all, then in View | New view, enable All Branches. Then set your search criteria: filenames (with wild cards) in the penultimate field. Finally: OK.

Answer (score 12):

Copy & paste this to use `git find-file SEARCHPATTERN`

Printing all searched branches:

```
git config --global alias.find-file '!for branch in `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads`; do echo "${branch}:"; git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | nl -bn -w3 | grep "$1"; done; :'
```

Print only branches with results:

```
git config --global alias.find-file '!for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads); do if git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | grep "$1" > /dev/null; then  echo "${branch}:"; git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | nl -bn -w3 | grep "$1"; fi; done; :'
```

These commands will add some minimal shell scripts directly to your `~/.gitconfig` as [global git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).

Comment: it is only searching in master branch

Comment: It search in all local branches

Comment: How do I get it to search all local and remote branches?

Comment: " How do I get it to search all local and remote branches?"  
First pull all the remote branches with:   


`git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done  
git fetch --all  
git pull --all
`

Answer (score 4):

This command finds commits which introduced specified paths:

```
git log --source --all --diff-filter=A --name-only -- '**/my_file.png'
```

Answer (score -3):

A quite decent implementation of the `find` command for Git repositories can be found here:

https://github.com/mirabilos/git-find