# Searching for a file in all Git branches

Tags: git, grep

How do I search all Git branches of a project for a file name?

I remember part of the filename (just the ending), so I'd like to be able to search for something like `*_robot.php` across all branches, and see which files match that. I'd preferably like to have it search history, and not just the HEADs of branches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search Git branches for a file or directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is one way:

```
git log --all --name-only --pretty=format: | sort -u | grep _robot.php
```

Comment: If you need to know the sha1 of the change, you can pass the 'before context' argument to grep, i.e. -B 100

git log --all --name-only --pretty=format: | sort -u | grep _robot.php -B 10

Comment: git log --all --name-only --pretty=format:'%H %f' | grep _robot.php -B 10

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simpler variation on @manojlds's solution: Git can indeed directly consider all the branches (`--all`), print the names of their modified files (`--name-only`), and only these names (`--pretty=format:`).

But Git can also first filter certain file names (regular expression) by putting the file name regular expression after the `--` separator:

```
git log --all --name-only --pretty=format: -- <file_name_regexp> | sort -u
```

So, you can directly do:

```
git log --all --name-only --pretty=format: -- _robot.php | sort -u
```

Comment: Great, now how do I see the latest contents of that file?

Comment: You can for instance do `git log --all --name-only --pretty=format:%H -- <file_name_regexp> | less` and look for the file name that you are interested in (by typing `/`, in `less`): the names of the modified files are preceded by their revision hash. (You then do the usual `git checkout <revision>` in order to see the file.)

Comment: Can you detail what does not work? I am confused about why it would not work, because this answer worked 3 years ago and still works with the current version of git, so I am not sure why it would fail for git 2.1.4, which was released in-between.

Comment: even prettier: `git log --all --name-only --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' -- '**/blob*' | less`