# Git Pull Synchronization

Tags: git

On my git, I have a file called b.txt

On my local machine, I do not have this file.

I tried "git pull" to retrieve the file from git and place it into the directory of my local machine, but it says:
Already up-to-date.

How do I retrieve the file without physically downloading it and placing it into my folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Is b.txt checked in to the remote repository?  Is your local repo tracking the branch to which it's checked in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are in a detached head mode: see "[Why did git detach my head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714)"

That would:

- make any `git pull` null ("already up-to-date")
- not restore your file if you had deleted locally

Note that you can search for the branches containing that file ("[How can I search Git branches for a file or directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory)"), and look for a deleted file ("[Git: How to search for a deleted file on the project history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203515/git-how-to-search-for-a-deleted-file-on-the-project-history)")