# Viewing any changes to a file on different git branches

Tags: git, branch

I'm convinced I've written a method in a different branch, but not the current one. Is there any way to view all changes to a file in different branches, ideally one that ignores branches merged into the current branch?

Comment: This sounds a lot like `git diff`... Is there a reason that is insufficient? What have you (or not) tried?

Answer (score 2):

To see all changes to files between two branches do the following:

```
git diff --stat <branch1> <branch2>
```

Then if you see the file that has changed between those two branches do:

```
git diff <branch1> <branch2> -- /path/to/file
```

If that's not enough, let me know.

Update: It appears this may be a duplicate of "[How can I search Git branches for a file or directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory)"

Comment: The trouble is not knowing which branch the file is in, and there are a fair few at the moment, so I'd like a way to look at all branches at the same time (local is probably enough, not remote).