# File ignored and now lost

Tags: git, git-log

I had a file "config.ru" in one of my branches (I can't remember which one), and at some point I added it to ".gitignore" (which may or may not be relevant -- I'm not sure).

Now I would like to find it in my history and view it.  I have tried `git log --all -- config.ru` but it produced no results.  How can I find the file?

Comment: was it at the root of the repo?

Comment: Yes, it was.  But for future reference, in addition to my OP, I'd like to know how to search the entire repo (eg, if I forgot everything about the location but the filename) if that's possible

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/372506/11343 : `git log --all -- **/config.ru`. So if it doesn't find anything the file was never tracked in any branch. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
git log --all --stat | grep -10 "config.ru"
```

--stat option shows the commit log with filename.

or

```
git log --walk-reflogs --stat | grep -10 "config.ru"
```

--walk-reflogs option shows the reflog commit intead of walking the commit ancestry chain.

Comment: now that is a "ton" of useful information.  so if i'm still not finding it, it means i must have been mistaken and never committed it before adding to .gitignore, correct?

Comment: Note that there's no reason the result can be different to the OP's command `git log --all -- filepath`