# Bash function to find all Git commits in which a file (whose name matches a regex) has *changed*

Tags: git, bash

I have [the following bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28095750/2736496), which searches for all files in a repository, whose filename matches a regular expression. It currently finds all commits in which a file *exists*. How can this be changed so it only searches among files that were *edited* (created, altered, or deleted) in each commit?

This was my original intention for the function. I was surprised to see the results being much broader than expected. The reason I'm trying to do this: I created a file a long time ago, and at some point between now and then, I accidentally deleted an important section from it. I want a list of all the points (commits) at which this file has changed, so I can quickly go back to the version containing the missing section, and paste it back into the current-commmit version.

```
:<<COMMENT
    Searches all commits in the current git repository containing a file whose name matches a regular expression.

    Usage: gitf <regex>

    Parameter is required, and must be at least one non-whitespace character.

    The original version of this function was based on the GitHub gist
    - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62d981890eccb48a99dc
    written by Stack Overflow user Handyman5
    - https://stackoverflow.com/users/459089/handyman5
    which is based on this SO question:
    - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory/372654#372654

    The main section of this function was authored by Stack Overflow user
    SwankSwashbucklers.
    - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615252/swankswashbucklers
    - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28095750/2736496

    Short description: Stored in GITF_DESC
COMMENT
#GITF_DESC: For "aliaf" command (with an 'f'). Must end with a newline.
GITF_DESC="gitf [searchterm]: Searches the current git repository for the file name that matches a regular expression.\n"
```

Body:

```
gitf()  {
    #Exit if no parameter is provided (if it's the empty string)
        param=$(echo "$1" | trim)
        echo "$param"
        if [ -z "$param" ]  #http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html
        then
          echo "Required parameter missing. Cancelled"; return
        fi

    wasFound="0";
    LOC=refs/remotes/origin # to search local branches only: 'refs/heads'
    ref="%(refname)"
    for branch in `git for-each-ref --format="$ref" $LOC`; do
        for commit in `git rev-list $branch | grep -oP ^.\{7\}`; do
            found=$(git ls-tree -r --name-only $commit | grep "$param")
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "${branch#$LOC/}: $commit:"
                while read line; do
                    echo "  $line"
                done < <(echo "$found")
                wasFound="1";
            fi
        done
    done

    if [ "$wasFound" -eq "0" ]; then
        echo "No files in this repository match '$param'."
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can live with a shell glob pattern rather than a full-blown regex, consider

```
git log -p --diff-filter=AMD --branches --tags -- "foo*bar.sh"
```

With `-p`, you see the deltas along with the commit message, author, SHA1, etc. The `--diff-filter=AMD` option selects only those commits in which the files in question were **A**dded, **M**odified, or **D**eleted. To search remotes as well as local branches and tags, use `--all` rather than `--branches --tags`. Finally, note the `--` that introduces path patterns, which you will want to quote to allow git to perform glob matching.

Comment: Note that with modern Git you can use extended glob pattern, with `**` matching any number of path components (i.e. matching also '/', which is not matched by `*`).

Comment: This prints out the body of each file. Based on the accepted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207414/how-to-show-changed-file-name-only-with-git-log), the `--name-only` and `--oneline` options dramatically improve it: `git log -p --name-only --oneline --diff-filter=AMD --branches --tags -- "*05_*"`.

Answer (score 4):

Use **`git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id`** (perhaps with `--stdin`) instead of `git ls-tree -r --name-only`.  Use `-m` or `-c` if you are interested in merges, `-M` or `-C` if you want to take into account respectively, rename and copy detection.

Or better parse output of `git diff-tree -r`.

Nb. the code given in question is seriously suboptimal (among others you check multiple times the same commits).

Comment: Can you elaborate on some of your suggested improvements?

Comment: @aliteralmind: Use `git rev-list --branches` once for all branches instead of once per branch.

Answer (score 2):

You could go through and use `git diff` to look at what changed between each of the commits.  Something like this:

```
for branch in `git for-each-ref --format="$ref" $LOC`;
do
    previous_commit=""
    for commit in `git rev-list $branch | grep -oP ^.\{7\}`;
    do
        if [ "$previous_commit" != "" ];
        then
            found=$(git diff --name-only $previous_commit $commit | grep "$param")
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then
                echo "${branch#$LOC/}: $commit:"
                while read line;
                do
                    echo "  $line"
                done < <(echo "$found")
                echo
                wasFound="1";
            fi
        fi
        previous_commit="$commit"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this function, which is based on [Greg Bacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123109/greg-bacon). I originally wanted regex, but globs fit the bill nicely. I also expected that a looping function would be required, but the single `git log` line is all that's needed.

First, a utility function:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable#comment21953456_3232433
alias trim="sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' -e 's/[[:space:]]*\$//g'"
```

Documentation header:

```
:<<COMMENT
   Searches all commits in the current git repository containing a file
   that has *changed*, whose name matches a glob. If the glob does not
   contain any asterisks, then it is surrounded by them on both sides.


   Usage:
      gitf "05"     #Equivalent to "*05*"
      gitf "05_*"

   Parameter is required, and must be at least one non-whitespace character.

   See:
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119379/bash-function-to-find-all-git-commits-in-which-a-file-whose-name-matches-a-rege/28120305
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094136/bash-function-to-search-git-repository-for-a-filename-that-matches-regex/28095750
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory/372654#372654

   The main "git log" line is based on this answer
   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119940/2736496
   by Stack Overflow user Greg Bacon
   - https://stackoverflow.com/users/123109/greg-bacon

   With thanks to SwankSwashbucklers
   - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615252/swankswashbucklers

   Short description: Stored in GITF_DESC
COMMENT
#GITF_DESC: For "aliaf" command (with an 'f'). Must end with a newline.
GITF_DESC="gitf [glob]: Searches all commits in the current git repository containing a file that has *changed*, whose name matches a glob.\n"
```

Body:

```
gitf()  {
   #Exit if no parameter is provided (if it's the empty string)
      param=$(echo "$1" | trim)
      echo "$param"
      if [ -z "$param" ]  #http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html
      then
        echo "Required parameter missing. Cancelled"; return
      fi

   #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash/229606#229606
   if [[ $param != *"*"* ]]
   then
     param="*$param*"
   fi

   echo "Searching for \"$param\"..."

   git log -p --name-only --oneline --diff-filter=AMD --branches --tags -- "$param"
}
```

Example output:

```
$ gitf 05_
05_
Searching for "*05_*"...
14e5cdd Quick save (no message): 01-21-2015__14_36_11
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
2efdeb1 Part four final. Changed auth/tests in post to auth/tests_login_basic.
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
526ca01 Part four final. Renamed auth/tests to test_basic_login, so Java doesn't need to parse the py file in future par
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
7c227f3 Escaped unescaped dollar-signs in initial_script_sh snippet, and added delete-all-but-.git command in comment at
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
e68a30a Part four final, moved post output folder into wordpress_posts.
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
3c5e4ec Part two final. Corrections/minor changes to all posts.
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
3a7dac9 Finished part one.
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
f87540e Initial commit
non_django_files/wordpress_posts/templates/05_login_remember_me.html
```