# How to find whether a file is present in multiple branches in git

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Is there a way in git to find whether a file is present in multiple branches or not? If so list the branch names. Please provide help on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search Git branches for a file or directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run in each branch this command:

```
git ls-files | grep YOUR FILE
```

And see if it appears.

Or you can do a more elaborated script like this:

```
for i in $(git branch | sed 's/\*//'); do git checkout $i; git ls-files | grep -q YOURFILE ; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "File found in branch: $i"; fi; done
```

Do a loop for each branch and do the same that the previous command.