# Git "fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path.." but no submodule reference found

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout

I have pulled a company repo down and started working; the initial branch was `master`.  In attempting to `git checkout` I'm encountering the following error consistently *(backslash = line break)*:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c \
    credential.helper=sourcetree checkout master 
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.  #so far, so good..


git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false \
     -c credential.helper=sourcetree submodule update --init --recursive 
fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/omnipay/pin'
Completed with errors, see above
```

I have searched for answers on this but all of them involve the presence of some reference to `submodule` somewhere, including [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185365/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodule-for-a-path-thats-not-a-submodule).  However:

1. `.git/config` - contains no reference to submodule(s) at all
2. `vendor/omnipay/pin` - this directory is empty including no hidden dot-files.
3. There is no string `submodule` in vendor/omnipay or even vendor/ for that matter

Again, other posts don't seem to apply as there is no file or submodule line to reference/remove.  What is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Comment: What's the output of `git ls-tree HEAD -- vendor/omnipay/pin`?

Comment: that returns `160000 commit 04e778e9689882d4c40419263014068b69b93168 vendor/omnipay/pin` - but I do know know what that means

Comment: Is there a `.gitmodules` file at the root of the repo (on `master`) and if so, can you edit your OP with its contents? (I would also advise `git log master -- .gitmodules` if no such file is present, to see if one ever existed.)

Comment: `git log master -- .gitmodules` returns nothing.  Your command does work for `-- index.php`, so I suppose .gitmodules never existed - or how could I search all branches?  This happens on checkout between any two branches.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

> that returns 160000 commit 04e778e9689882d4c40419263014068b69b93168 vendor/omnipay/pin

It is a "gitlink", a special entry in the index, recording the sHA1 for the root tree of a nested Git repository.
That is why the folder appears empty: it is a placeholder, for a nested repository.

If you have a `.gitmodules` file, there should be an entry mentioning *where* to look for the remote repository which is supposed to be checked out at that path.

If not, try at least a `git rm vendor/omnipay/pin` (no trailing slash), followed by a `git submodule update --init --recursive`