# How to find a file in git?

Tags: git

I know that at some point I had a file in a certain path. Now, this file doesn't exist anymore. I didn't delete it from git. I'm not sure I added it? At any rate I didn't do any destructive action.

How can I find out which commit or stash this file is in?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/372506/2020827

Answer (score 3):

The `--follow` option of `git-log` is for looking for a particular file.

```
git log --follow -- <filename>
```