# How can I find which branch contains a version of a specific file with a specific string?

Tags: git, grep

We have a zillion branches and someone reverted important changes. Is there a way to find:

- which (local or remote) branch contains
- the version of `file.js`
- which contains `searchString`?

I've found answers to how to find a file in multiple branches, or how to find a string in multiple branches. But not how to find the version of a file containing the specified string in multiple branches.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory cover it?

Comment: You can probably amend that to use `git log -p --all -- file.js` and search your string in the output, which gets you the proper commit, and then you can use `git branch -a --contains`. There's probably even a way to do it in one go.

Comment: Actually, found a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the Git commit that introduced a string in any branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816134/how-to-find-the-git-commit-that-introduced-a-string-in-any-branch)

Comment: No, neither are duplicates. The first one is about how to find a specific file, the second is how to find a specific string. But not a specific string in a specific file in any branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the two answers from the suggested duplicate questions like this:

`git log -S "searchString" --source --all -- file.js`