# How do I list git branches with commits only to a specific directory?

Tags: git

Our team commits to a big git repository.

Recently we've decided to export one of subdirectories (named framework) to a separate repo and remove all branches that contain commits only to that subdirectory.

How can I list such branches?

I've modified [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/372654/704329) to get:

```sh
for branch in `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin `; do 
    git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | grep -q "framework/" && echo $branch 
done
```

However this command returns branches with commits to other subdirectories too.

I've tried expanding this snippet:

```sh
for branch in `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin `; do 
    if git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | grep -q "framework/" ; then
        if ! git ls-tree -r --name-only $branch | grep -vq "framework/" ; then
            echo $branch 
        fi
    fi
done
```

However, this command prints nothing.

Comment: If you just remove the directories entirely with [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/), empty commits and branches should be pruned automatically. Did you actually want the list you asked for, or were you only planning to delete the branches on it?

Comment: Yes, I actually want the list, with names of committers. I wanted to notify my team mates that I'm going to remove those branches.

Comment: Why not just filter a clone of the repo and then diff its branch list with the original? You're going to filter the repo eventually anyway, right?

Comment: Right. Will go and try that tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `framework/` is part of your repo, all branches contain a directory named `framework/`, so your `git ls-tree` command will always list something.

---

If you have a reference branch (say `master` or `develop`), you can check if a branch has modified this directory since it forked from that branch :

```sh
# will give view an understandable view of what commits are part of this branch :
git log --graph --oneline master..$branch -- framework/

# will give you an int as output (easier to use in a script) :
git rev-list --count master..$branch -- framework/
```

You can use an alternative syntax to `a..b` if you want to exclude several "reference branches" :

```sh
# count commits from $branch that modified 'framework/' since it forked
# either from master or from develop :
git rev-list --count ^master ^develop $branch -- framework/
```

Comment: Could you post complete solution to the original question? 