# Git compare one file in another commit

Tags: git

I have a few questions:

1. How do I find/search for a specific file in all of my past commits? Let's say, I want to find the the file test.py in all of my past commits. I don't want it to search the regular information such as commit message, author, date, etc..
2. Once I find this file, in step 1 above; How would I compare test.py in another commit to the same file in any other commit? I could use the `git diff <commit_id> test.py <commit_id> test.py`?

I am not talking about comparing working directory to staged or staged to last commit.

ok. So I know how to find files in past commits. For the results below I used, `git --pretty=oneline card.py`

But, how do I compare the file based on this output:

```
6c40f05c9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Added debugger.py and time-your-code.py
fa7219963 Python Generators
```

Comment: I think your first question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory ?

Comment: `git diff --help` shows, among others, usage like `git diff [<options>] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]`, which is probably what you looking for.

Comment: How do I find a specific file in past commits?

Comment: I know how to locate the file in past commits. git log test.py. Based on your syntax above, how would I compare the file based on commit ID or blob?

Comment: @MattPaolini : 9769953 quoted the doc, when applied to your case it reads : `git diff fa7219963 6c40f05c9 -- card.py`

Comment: Also : do take time to read the docs for `git log`, which has a ton of options to display stuff from your repo. For example : the `-p` option adds the diff after each commit : `git log --oneline -p -- card.py`

Answer (score 0):

Comments already pointed out all the right steps, I'm merely consolidating into a single answer readers can use:

Say you want to compare your file `card.py` to historical revisions, you can use a 2-step method:

1. Check which commits changed that file using `git log --pretty=oneline card.py`. Output should looke similar to:

```
570cf4c17d6b7a5a2dae7a57739a9ca07987631e Add something
e961dc9c5cef37cc94841fbddfbfa88471a329da Add something else
ab385ef517e9d6ee4ec27b4e8c318aa76bb8dc66 Revise something
a1421b529300a8279db3aec004f27359a4346f3b Revise something else
```

2. Compare your existing version to an older one using `git diff e961dc9c5cef37cc94841fbddfbfa88471a329da -- card.py`