# How to delete a specific object from all branches in github/gitlab

Tags: git, file, object, gitlab, branch

Lets assume that I have 100 branches and each branches have file1,file2.....file10. Now I want to delete file2 from all of 100 branches. What should I do to delete that from all branches?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)) for that (since [`git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309) are obsolete after Git 2.22 or more)

Use a [path-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_filtering_based_on_paths_see_also_filename_callback):

```
git filter-repo --path file2 --invert-path
```

Its [man page mentions](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#solving-this-with-filter-branch=), about `git filter-branch`:

> Despite the use of `--all` and `--tag-name-filter`, and filter-branch's manpage claiming that a clone is enough to get rid of old objects, the extra steps to delete the other tags and do another `gc` are still required to clean out the old objects and avoid mixing new and old history before pushing somewhere.

`git filter-repo` will [force you to make a backup first](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#FRESHCLONE), then proceed to change the history of the local repository you are filtering.
Check that all branches have been cleaned up, by [looking for `file2` in all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/372970/6309).

```
git log --all -- file2
```